# Create sunburst plot in Shiny using HTML instead of sunburstOutput

Tags: r, html, shiny, sunburst-diagram

Dear members of the community,

I am using the `R` package `sunburstR` in order to create a sunburst plot into `Shiny`. The code below works perfect and I am able to create the plot, however, I would like to remove the legend completely. For this reason I know that using HTML5 I will be able to play more with the parameters of the plot.

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sunburstR)
library(data.table)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar( 
  sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Sunburst Plot", tabName = "sunbrstPlot")

  )
  ),

  dashboardBody( tabBox(id = "sunbrstPlot", width = "100%", height = "1000px",
                sunburstOutput("sunburstPlot", height = "750", width = "100%")
                )

  )
  )         

server <- function(input, output) { 

# Create Sunburst plot
output$sunburstPlot <- renderSunburst({ 

tempDat <-  data.table(A=sample(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 100)), B = sample(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 100)), C = sample(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 100))) 
tempDat[,c("V1","V2"):= list(paste0(A,"-",B, "-", C),1)]
sunburst(tempDat[,.(V1,V2)])

})

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The HTML5 code that is written for this chart is:

```
print(sunburstOutput("sunburstPlot", height = "750", width = "100%"))

<div class="sunburst html-widget html-widget-output" id="sunburstPlot" style="width:100%; height:750px;  position:relative;">
  <div>
    <div class="sunburst-main">
      <div class="sunburst-sequence"></div>
      <div class="sunburst-chart">
        <div class="sunburst-explanation" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sunburst-sidebar">
      <input type="checkbox" class="sunburst-togglelegend">Legend</input>
      <div class="sunburst-legend" style="visibility:hidden;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was thinking that if could modify the HTML code and incorporate it into the `dashboardBody` I would be able to reproduce the chart and maybe get rid off the legend in the future:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(sunburstR)
library(data.table)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),

  dashboardSidebar( 
  sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Sunburst Plot", tabName = "sunbrstPlot")

  )
  ),

  dashboardBody( tabBox(id = "sunbrstPlot", width = "100%", height = "1000px",
                #sunburstOutput("sunburstPlot", height = "750", width = "100%")

                tags$div(class="sunburst html-widget html-widget-output", id="sunburstPlot", style="width:100%; height:750px;  position:relative;",

                                        tags$div(
                                            tags$div(class = "sunburst-main",
                                                tags$div(class="sunburst-sequence"),
                                                tags$div(class="sunburst-chart",
                                                    tags$div(class="sunburst-explanation", style="visibility:hidden;")
                                                            )
                                                    ), tags$div(class="sunburst-sidebar",
                                                            tags$input(type="checkbox", class="sunburst-togglelegend", "Legend"),
                                                            tags$div(class="sunburst-legend", style="visibility:hidden;")
                                                                )
                                                )

                                             )



                )

  )
  )         

server <- function(input, output) { 

# Create Sunburst plot
output$sunburstPlot <- renderSunburst({ 

tempDat <-  data.table(A=sample(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 100)), B = sample(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 100)), C = sample(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"), 100))) 
tempDat[,c("V1","V2"):= list(paste0(A,"-",B, "-", C),1)]
sunburst(tempDat[,.(V1,V2)])

})

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately following this approach I am not able to reproduce the chart. Could you provide assistance with this?

Thank you for your time on my question.

Cheers,
Kostas

Comment: If the legend is created from the server end I wonder if just changing the ui part would be enough to get rid of the legend (as you are still using `renderSunburst`)

Comment: I think you are right. Do you think there is a way to work with HTML5 and play with various parameters of the plot?

Comment: You can get rid of everything but the checkbox by adding `legend = list(w = 0, h = 0, s = 0, t = 0)` to the `sunburst` call. Getting rid of that seems harder; you might try external CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@warmoverflow answer should work ok, but the code below will show some possibly more robust methods for achieving your objective.  I will comment inline in the code to try to describe the approaches.

```
library(sunburstR)
sequences <- read.csv(
  system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",package="sunburstR")
  ,header = FALSE
  ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sunburst(sequences)
```

#### option 1 - htmlwidgets::onRender

We can use `htmlwidgets::onRender` to remove the legend after the sunburst is drawn.

```
htmlwidgets::onRender(
  sunburst(sequences),
  '
function(el,x){
  d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-sidebar").remove()
}
  '
)
```

#### option 2 - replace the sunburst_html function

`htmlwidgets` allows the use of a custom html function to define the container for the `htmlwidget`.  We can see the function for sunburstR with `sunburstR:::sunburst_html`.  In this approach, we will replace `sunburstR:::sunburst_html` with a custom html function without the legend.

```
library(htmltools)
sunburst_html <- function(id, style, class, ...){
  tagList(
    tags$div(
      id = id, class = class, style = style, style="position:relative;"
      ,tags$div(
        tags$div(class = "sunburst-main"
           , tags$div( class = "sunburst-sequence" )
           , tags$div( class = "sunburst-chart"
             ,tags$div( class = "sunburst-explanation", style = "visibility:hidden;")
           )
        )
        # comment this out so no legend
        #,tags$div(class = "sunburst-sidebar"
        #  , tags$input( type = "checkbox", class = "sunburst-togglelegend", "Legend" )
        #    , tags$div( class = "sunburst-legend", style = "visibility:hidden;" )
        )
    )
  )
}

# replace the package sunburst_html with our custom function
#  defined above
assignInNamespace("sunburst_html", sunburst_html, "sunburstR")

sunburst(sequences)
```

Comment: I think your suggestion is just amazing. I even used the first option and it worked great for me as my shiny has a very complicated structure and applying the first post I was not able to affect the plot with JS. Thank you very much for your suggestion this opens a complete new way of approaching it. Cheers!

Comment: just a note, the first option works great, but if you expect multiple sunburst on a page or in an app, the second might be more convenient since all sunbursts created after that is run in a session will be created without the legend.

Comment: next version should allow `legend = FALSE` to completely disable legend without hacks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to hide the legend. Add the following below `menuItem` (remember to add a `,` after the `menuItem` line

```
  tags$head(tags$script(HTML("
                         $(document).ready(function(e) {
                            $('.sunburst-sidebar').hide();
                         })
                         ")))
```

If you prefer, you can even completely remove it (change `hide` to `remove`).

Comment: Thank you very much for providing this information. In this example it works great. I have created a dynamic app with dynamic ```menuItems``` and these are render as ```sideBarMenuOutput``` and I am trying to do the same but it does not work. If you have any idea on this I would appreciate it. Thanks for your time

Comment: Is there an other way to use it in CSS?

Comment: It doesn't have to be below menuitem. You can also put it below or above tabbox.