# How can I remove the Legend and check box from a rendered sunburstR figure in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, legend, sunburst-diagram

I managed to remove the legend function but I still get the "Legend" label with a checkbox. Where in the code in the sunburstR package can I remove this or if there's an easier method I'm all ears? thanks.

Comment: Could you share your code? It would help. And have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39921971/create-sunburst-plot-in-shiny-using-html-instead-of-sunburstoutput

Comment: Thanks yes I saw that. I was looking for what I need to change in the sunburt.js file in the library package file for example. I've commented out everything I see that is to do with the legend but I still get the checkbox and label 'Legend'. The functionality stopped working though.

Comment: Maybe you could post what you have so far.

Comment: unfortunately the code is too lengthy but essentially anywhere "legend" appears in the library file sunburst.js I removed it.

Comment: the developer of the library made mention today of putting in an option to remove the legend if desired and apparently within the next couple of days. So that's awesome

Answer (score 0):

Version 2.0.0 of `sunburstR`, released 2018-03-12 [on CRAN](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=sunburstR), includes a `legend` argument that can be set to `FALSE`.

for example...

```
library(sunburstR)

sequences <- read.csv(
  system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",package="sunburstR")
  ,header = FALSE
  ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)[1:100,]

sunburst(sequences, legend = FALSE)
```